# Why doesn't my gremlin query give an output?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I have run into some errors with my gremlin console.

I have the following lines of code:

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
graph.io(graphml()).readGraph('air-routes.graphml')
```

i then do the following:

```
g.V(2)
```

And this gives no output. in fact whenever i put in a number into V() nothing pops out when it should. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the id manager to use `LONG` identifiers:

```
conf = new BaseConfiguration()
conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager", "LONG")
conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager", "LONG")
conf.setProperty("gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexPropertyIdManager", "LONG")
graph = TinkerGraph.open(conf)
graph.io(graphml()).readGraph("air-routes.graphml")
```

See [Loading the air-routes graph using the Gremlin console](http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#ld).